# Select only one option per div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of div's with options inside them, I have already written some jQuery which selects only one option.

Now I want to select only one option(class=choice) per div(class=blahblah).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="blahblah"id="finish_colour">
<div class="choice"></div>
<div class="choice"></div>
<div class="choice"></div>
</div>

<div class="blahblah"id="main_colour">
<div class="choice"></div>
<div class="choice"></div>
<div class="choice"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('.choice').click(function(){

    $('.choice').not(this).removeClass('selected_choice');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected_choice');
});
```

The div's all have the same class, but different id's if thats any help.

Comment: Please post your HTML and/or a jsFiddle example.

Comment: Show some HTML for better understanding

Comment: I have added an example of the HTML i'm using too, don't think the answers below are any help(mostly because my lack of HTML and poor explanation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your html is like this,

```
<div>
  <div class="choice"></div>
  <div class="choice"></div>
  <div class="choice"></div>
</div>
```

You can modify it to be per divs like this,

```
$('.blahblah .choice').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.choice').removeClass('selected_choice');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected_choice');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this...

```
$('.choice').click(function(){
    var myDiv = $(this);
    $('.choice').removeClass('selected_choice');
    myDiv.toggleClass('selected_choice');
});
```